# How to change default shown layer of QGIS project in standalone Python app?

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, layers, zoom, standalone

I'm developping a Python standalone app that needs a dynamic map (with the zoom and pan tools).

I chose to use PyQGIS that allows me to work with QGIS projects. I managed to create a class that takes a path to a project, loads it and displays it. However, by default, the largest layer is shown which may be a problem.

My QGIS project (that can vary, it depends on the needs) has the world's map as its largest layer with some smaller layers, for example a specific town. I want to give to my class a layer (throught a name or id) that will be shown by default (the canvas will be zoomed to that layer).

How can I do it ?

I want to add that, obviously, I searched for a solution before asking my question and tried some options with the QgsMapCanvas' methods (zoomToFeatureExtent and the more simple method zoomIn). But I can't make it work. I don't get any error whatsoever. If I check the extent of the canvas, it's well set (the same as the layer i chose) but I don't have the wanted result on the screen. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Here's the code I have that show my QGIS project in a canvas (I deleted the part where i add the zoom and pan tool to make it less long, I don't think it's needed) :

```py
class MyWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,path):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        self.canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)

        self.project = QgsProject.instance()
        self.bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(self.project.layerTreeRoot(), self.canvas)
        self.project.read(path)

        self.canvas.freeze(True)
        self.canvas.refresh()
        self.canvas.freeze(False)
        self.canvas.repaint()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)
```

Comment: How did you use `zoomToFeatureExtent()` ?

Comment: @JULESG
I don't have the specific code anymore so please don't mind the potential syntax errors. It was something like this :

`layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('name')[0]
self.canvas.zoomToFeatureExtent(layer.extent())`

I might use it the wrong way though.

Comment: Instead of `self.project = QgsProject.instance()` try to use `self.project = QgsProject()` and then replace every `QgsProject.instance()` by `self.project`

That's what I did in my plugin and it seems to work

Comment: @JULESG
It doesn't really change anything, I now have an exit code different from 0 but that's it (-1073741819). I changed self.project and used it in the line just as you said.

Answer (score 2):

I find that the `QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge` is causing some trouble for zooming on a specific layer because it updates the canvas automatically.

You have to remove it from your code to make it work, here is a snippet that allows me to zoom on a specific layer, `"Layer 3"`, in a `QMainWindow`:

```
class MapViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas()
        self.canvas.setCanvasColor(Qt.white)

        path = "test.qgz"
        self.project = QgsProject().instance()
        self.project.read(path)

        # List the layers in your project and add them to your canvas
        layers = [layer for layer in self.project.mapLayers().values()]
        layers.reverse() # reverse to keep the layer order from the project
        self.canvas.setLayers(layers)

        # Get the layers you want to zoom in by name
        layer = self.project.mapLayersByName("Layer 3")[0]
        self.canvas.zoomToFeatureExtent(layer.extent())

        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)
```

Screenshot of the project `test.qgz` open in QGIS and open in a `QMainWindow` with a zoom on `"Layer 3"` :

[image: Screenshot of the result]

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works now (still need to correct a few things but at least it's zoomed). I really appreciate it.
Do you mind sharing the source where you found the information ?

Comment: At first I supposed the `QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge` was mandatory because of this :https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadproject.html#loading-projects but then I found this page wich doesn't use it : https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/canvas.html#using-map-tools-with-canvas Finally if you look at the description of the class it describe the fact that it update the canvas : https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.16/gui/QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge.html#qgis.gui.QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the proper way to deal with this problem is to add the following line after declaring an instance of `QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge`.

E.g.

```py
self.bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(self.project.layerTreeRoot(), self.canvas)
self.bridge.setAutoSetupOnFirstLayer(False)
```

You can then use the `setExtent()` method of the `QgsMapCanvas` class to set the canvas extent to a layer extent. The advantage of this method over `zoomToFeatureExtent()` is that it works for both raster and vector layers. If you wish to zoom out slightly from the layer extent you can add a call to `zoomByFactor()` and pass a float value slightly greater than 1.

Below is a minimal but complete standalone script example. Just change the project path and layer name.

```py
from qgis.core import QgsApplication, QgsProject, QgsRasterLayer
from qgis.gui import QgsMapCanvas, QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class myWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, path, layer_name):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        
        self.path = path
        self.layer_name = layer_name
        
        self.setGeometry(150, 150, 750, 500)
        self.canvas = QgsMapCanvas(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)
        self.project = QgsProject.instance()
        self.bridge = QgsLayerTreeMapCanvasBridge(self.project.layerTreeRoot(), self.canvas)
        self.bridge.setAutoSetupOnFirstLayer(False)
        self.project.read(self.path)
        self.layer = self.project.mapLayersByName(self.layer_name)[0]
        self.canvas.setExtent(self.layer.extent())
        self.canvas.zoomByFactor(1.1)
        self.canvas.refresh()
        

def main():
    app = QApplication([])
    qgs = QgsApplication([], False)
    qgs.setPrefixPath("C:/OSGeo4W64/apps/qgis", True)
    qgs.initQgis()
    
    project_path = 'C:\\Users\\Path\\To\\Your_project.qgs'
    name = 'Layer_name'
    
    w = myWindow(project_path, name)
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Result:

[image]